# Salesforce multiple if statement

Tags: formula

Hi guys I just want to get total no of days spent in between the dates,`project_completion_date__c` is date field and converted to datetimevalue as created date is `DATETIME` datatype. Here is my formula it's throwing following error

> Incorrect argument type for function 'ISNULL()'

Any one have an idea about this error?

```
IF(ISNULL(Project_Completion_Date__c), 
   (Now() - CreatedDate),
IF(NOT(ISNULL(Project_Completion_Date__c <> NULL)),(DATETIMEVALUE(Project_Completion_Date__c) - CreatedDate), 
1) 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems in your formula.

First, you use the `ISNULL` function with a boolean inside `Project_Completion_Date__c <> NULL` instead of only the `Project_Completion_Date__c` field.

Then, you don't need to check if the field is not null, you're already in a `IF` function.

So here's the right formula:

```
IF(ISNULL(Project_Completion_Date__c), 
   Now() - CreatedDate,
   DATETIMEVALUE(Project_Completion_Date__c) - CreatedDate,
)
```

Comment: How foolish am I?. Thanks for your review Martin.

Comment: @Laxman Alternatively: `BLANKVALUE(DATETIMEVALUE(Project_Completion_Date__c), NOW()) - CreatedDate`